# successfully imported csv data into python but many floats are converted to objects

Tags: python-2.7, csv

All,

I have imported a csv file into python but a lot of float variables get converted to objects. I have tried different methods to convert them back to float but it does not work (not sure why?)

```py
data=pd.read_csv("path\filename.csv")
data['x']=data['x'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

data['x'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

What shall I do? read the data as txt? or read it as excel file?

Comment: show us your data

Comment: @Patrick . would like to but not sure how to attach a file?

Comment: Edit your question and copy&pase some of the data into a code tag (indented by 4 spaces) - probably best to give the first few lines with header and then some lines that give you problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[['upload_date','Gross Loan Amount','Loan Amount']]
     upload_date Gross Loan Amount     Loan Amount
0     12/03/2018          864,053      -864,052.77
1     12/03/2018        1,765,824    -1,765,823.78
2     12/03/2018          859,714      -859,713.72
3     12/03/2018       32,400,556   -32,400,556.13
4     12/03/2018          553,856      -553,855.66
5     12/03/2018        2,715,921    -2,715,921.29
6     12/03/2018           54,913       -54,913.32
7     12/03/2018        5,156,250     5,156,250.00
8     12/03/2018       14,190,000    14,190,000.00

upload_date          object
Gross Loan Amount    object
Loan Amount          object
dtype: object
```